# Paragraph not appearing html/css

Tags: html, css

I want to add a description after every picture that is displayed and I only want it to appear when the image is selected. Adding a paragraph doesn't seem to work, nothing appears.

Here is my html and css - I am not allowed to use any javascript

```css
#gallery {
  width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 100px auto;
 
}

#bar {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

#bar li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

#bar li a img {
  display: block;
  border: none;
}

#bar li a {
  display: block;
}

#big {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Image Gallery</title>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  
 </head>
 <body>
  

 <div id="gallery">
     <ul id="bar">
       <li><a href="#pic1"><img alt="" src="rsz_autumn.jpg" /></a> </li>
       <li><a href="#pic2"><img alt="" src="rsz_lake.jpg" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="#pic3"><img alt="" src="rsz_mountain.jpg" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="#pic4"><img alt="" src="rsz_mountainlake.jpg" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="#pic5"><img alt="" src="rsz_path.jpg" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="#pic6"><img alt="" src="rsz_sea.jpg" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="#pic7"><img alt="" src="rsz_sky.jpg" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="#pic8"><img alt="" src="rsz_sun.jpg" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="#pic9"><img alt="" src="rsz_trail.jpg" /></a></li>
     </ul>
  <div id="big">
    <div><a name="pic1"></a> <img alt="" src="autumn.jpg" /><p>A picture about autumn.</p></div>
    <div><a name="pic2"></a><img alt="" src="lake.jpg" /></div>
    <div><a name="pic3"></a><img alt="" src="mountain.jpg" /></div>
    <div><a name="pic4"></a><img alt="" src="mountainlake.jpg" /></div>
    <div><a name="pic5"></a><img alt="" src="path.jpg" /></div>
    <div><a name="pic6"></a><img alt="" src="sea.jpg" /></div>
    <div><a name="pic7"></a><img alt="" src="sky.jpeg" /></div>
    <div><a name="pic8"></a><img alt="" src="sun.jpg" /></div>
    <div><a name="pic9"></a><img alt="" src="trail.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a css hack with limitation, see breakdown

Add an input checkbox for each image element

Add a label for each input box

Hide the input box

When the user clicks the label, the input box is check

As a result of the box being checked, we can use the `:checked` pseudo to apply a style to our sibling elemnent. In this case it may be a caption

See snippet below

```css
#gallery {
  width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

a {
  pointer-events: none
}

#bar {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  display: inline;

}

input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked~.text {
  opacity:1;
}

.text {
  opacity:0;
}

#bar li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

#bar li a img {
  display: block;
  border: none;
}

#bar li a {
  display: block;
}

#big {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
  <div id="gallery">
    <ul id="bar">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="rad1">
        <label for="rad1">
             <a href="#"><img alt="" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTzvF_fKLwUk_0nbMnHMJYw4sIiU78lMhMOLTlqvhJ8XrGkqhL_jw" /></a> </label>
        <div class="text">
          <h1>This is a caption</h1>
        </div>
      </li>
      <br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <div id="pic1"></div>

    </ul>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to control your code. However, I think you can use :hover selector. Please see [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_gallery_responsive) adding this css: `.gallery .desc {visibility:hidden;} .gallery:hover .desc {visibility:visible;}`. You can add also a transition effect. I hope I was of any help.